# How to parse the sentence: " I’m the same person I was before I made the series that I am now. "

Tags: sentence-construction

The sentence is from the VOA Learning English Program:

> “Well actually, the fame is there -- it just takes a different form. I
>   mean, you know, you, you think of our show being prime time, but when
>   I come out here and I meet people, they’re just as excited as I was
>   during Batman days. So, it’s not that the people change. Maybe, you
>   know, the, the perception is different, but it, honestly, nothing has
>   changed – ***I’m the same person I was before I made the series that I am
>   now.***”

My understanding is : 
I am the same person that I was before I made the series and I am the same person that I am now.
How to parse this sentence ?

Comment: *That I am now* seems superfluous to me.

Comment: @snailboat You know what, I agree with you.

Comment: I don't know anything about "the VOA Learning English Program", but it doesn't look at all like a well-formed English sentence to me. I can't imagine what sort of creative educationalist thinks such weird (ungrammatical?!) phrasing is a useful example to learners.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, certainly the example isn't one that should be imitated, but on the other hand it's a perfectly good example of what people actually say, and as such is a reasonable example for learners to come to understand.  I think most native speakers will understand it quickly and effortlessly.

Comment: Well, to the extent that it's an example of an error, it's "perfectly good" . . .

Comment: @jwpat7: The only answer so far clearly indicates it's not that effortless to understand the utterance. Not surprising, really, since it's effectively gibberish which is impossible to "parse". We only know what it means because it's such a trite sentiment we can guess what the speaker is trying to say once we read words like **I, same person, before, now**. OP has understood that, so there isn't really anything else left to say except what snailboat and myself have said. So I'm closevoting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks "how to parse" a totally non-grammatical utterance (that happens to have a relatively transparent meaning).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You do not know whether something is ungrammatical until you attempt to parse it, and if you don't know how (English learner!) then you cannot make a conclusion. "Ungrammatical stuff will happen" in a learner site.

Comment: @Kaz: I don't disagree, and I don't intend my closevote to be seen as in any way critical of OP for posting the question. But to me it's on a par with people asking about the meaning of some usage which turns out to be a typo (or even an error by a non-native speaker). It's a matter of common politeness to enlighten the OP, but often those questions really have no reason for being preserved in what is to a considerable extent a *knowledge base*, rather than just an ephemeral Q&A site.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see your point. Basically a mistake is "too localized"; it helps the OP, but is of little use to future visitors. Nevertheless, questions closed for such a reason stick around anyway. If it doesn't belong in the knowledge base, it should be actually turfed.

Comment: @Kaz: True. I'm not sure if the option still exists, but we used to be able to vote to *delete* questions on ELU. I expect mods can still do this unilaterally, but I've rarely cast such votes myself. I must admit that in this case your answer goes a long way to justifying the question being here at all (it explains *why* the text is ungrammatical, rather than wasting effort explaining what the speaker meant). Had you answered earlier I might well not have closevoted, but my one vote obviously isn't the be-all-and-end-all anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is talking about one person, but speaking of that person as if it were two people.

A sentence similar to this one is often heard when talking about someone who entered into sudden riches; for example:

> I am the same person now as I was before I won the lottery.

That's a way of saying, "Money hasn't changed me," or "Money hasn't changed who I am."

In contrast, we have this one:

> I am not the same person I was before I went to prison that I am now.

This time, the speaker is saying that he has changed in some way (for the better, we hope).

Now, back to your sentence:

> I’m the same person I was before I made the series that I am now.

The meaning might be a little clearer if it were written as:

> I’m the same person now as I was before I made the series.

The following isn't a true "parsing," but it may help you parse the original sentence:

> The (person I was before I made the series) and (the person I am now) are the same person.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is ungrammatical. Or rather, it is grammatical but with semantics that is nosense.  These two are grammatical and sound:

> I was same person that I am now.
>
> I am the same person (that) I was before I made the series.

In the sentence being considered, the complementized clause "that I am now" is dangling. It looks like "the series that I am now" which is grammatical, but semantically, it is nonsense.

A way to change the sentence so that it incorporates "that I am now" and has sound semantics is as follows:

> The person that I am now is the same person that I was before I made the series.

An example of a semantically sound sentence which is closely parallel to yours, in terms of syntax, but with a different meaning, is this:

> I am quite a different person from what I was before I created the person that I am now.

This works because "the person that I am now" is sensible, unlike "the series that I am now".